# I feel like the more I improve the structure of my program I am writing a DSL

Tags: design, javascript, typescript

My project started out as spaghetti code. The more DRY and extensible I make my code, the more it looks like configuration files and code than runs them.

Is that a good thing or does that mean I am doing something wrong?

I am writing a program the scrapes semistructured data from websites and transforms it into a common format.

I am building a recipe parser, which parses different microformats into a common format.

Comment: Post real code examples on codereview.stackexchange, and you will get some experts opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that a good thing or does that mean I am doing something wrong?

Without any more information and a concrete code sample, no, writing a DSL is not necessarily a bad thing. A DSL is a common design pattern if you have a lot of common logic. At some point, you may want to take it further and actually write it as a proper DSL.